# Appcenter Push iOS - control when to ask for push permission

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I can't seem to control AppCenter when to ask for push permissions. As soon as I'm invoking `AppCenter.Start(..., typeof(Push));` it immediately asks for the permission. I also tried to disable Push before invoking Start by `Push.SetEnabledAsync(true);` but that didn't help. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Hi , do you have a try with apple native notification , and whether it work ? You can check the notification wheter work without App Center .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/faq), has a section for this question:

> Can I delay showing the Push Notifications permission pop-up until the user click a button or a certain screen?

Basically, you initialize AppCenter at the start of your app

```
AppCenter.Start("{KEY}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

And then after login, you can just call

```
AppCenter.Start(typeof(Push));
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to work with conditionals when implementing the app center .start.